# jQuery slideUp() is Choppy with Nested Divs

Tags: jquery, animation

My HTML is as follows. There are multiple instances of this since I'm pulling from a database and using a `while` loop.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="some_stuff">content1</div>
    <div class="more_stuff">content2</div>
    <div class="delete">
        <a href="#" id="itemID" class="deleteContainer">Delete</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$(function() {
$(".deleteContainer").click(function() {
    var container=$(this).closest("div.container");
    var containerid = $(this).attr("id");

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "delete.php",
        data: "id=" + containerid,
        cache: false,
        success: function() {
            container.slideUp(500, function() {$(this).remove();});
        }
    });
return false;
});
});
```

The idea is that a 'delete' link inside each container causes the appropriate field to be deleted from the database and, upon success, the appropriate container slides up and is removed. `delete.php` works fine, and the animation effect is mostly functioning. The problem I'm having is that the `slideUp` doesn't slide but instead happens in two parts: first, what appears to be the margin on the bottom of `<div class="container">` disappears instantly (no sliding effect), then after about a fourth of a second the rest of `<div class="container">` disappears. The database call works fine--the appropriate content is removed, and the page correctly renders on subsequent visits. I just can't figure out what's going on with the animation (tested in Safari, Opera, Chrome, and Firefox).

In testing if it was an AJAX issue, such as a delay in the server response, I tried:

```
$(window).load(function(){
    $(".container").click(function(){
        $(this).slideToggle(500);
    });
});
```

That still has the same problem of `slideUp()` occurring in pieces, so I'm guessing this has to do with jQuery and the HTML structure (maybe the nested `<div>`s?). Other scenarios of `slideUp()` on the same page work fine.

Comment: use jsFiddle.net please so we can see it

Comment: Made additional edits after submitting that. Without the CSS it works fine. With CSS (http://jsFiddle.net/UPNhx/6/), it goes in pieces.

Comment: i think I can see the problem..on my screen, as the div disappears there are horizontal red lines that appear for a split second as if the animation were lagging or something..p.s. i changed the container background to red

Comment: oook now i see ur problem. ill work on it

Comment: I have had this problem before too..I was looking through ur CSS and saw this line: `min-height: 125px;` ..min-height is notorious for breaking the fluid sliding animation in jQuery. I am not sure why exactly. Is it possible to make this fixed like: `height: 125px;` or do you NEED it fluid? Try changing your min-height to just height and you will see it works

Comment: [The suggested fix is here](http://jsfiddle.net/UPNhx/8/), but I have quite a dilemma whether to use .height() or .css('height') with parseInt, or is there some better way to get rid of that min-height ?